# ORA-01857: not a valid time zone

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to convert from UTC time zone to GMT time zone.

I ran this below query and getting ORA error.

```
select NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'UTC', 'GMT') from dual;
```

And error is

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'UTC', 'GMT') from dual
Error report -
ORA-01857: not a valid time zone
```

I googled and find that NEW_TIME function is not accepting UTC time zone.

So, Can you please suggest me alternate solution/any way to convert from UTC to GMT?

Comment: `UTC` is (more or less) the same as `GMT` - Term `GMT` is just the "old style", see [UTC vs GMT](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/learn/utc-vs-gmt/)

Answer (score 1):

`UTC` is also known as `GMT`, the latter which `NEW_TIME` already accepts.  So, what you are trying to is equivalent to:

```
SELECT NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'GMT')
FROM dual;
```

The call to `NEW_TIME` doesn't make any sense of course.  Check [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/new_time.php) for a list of accepted timezone codes.

Comment: Thank you @Tim for your reply. But my code is in production, and here I hard coded value UTC. but originally in code it is taking as $TIMEZONE (i.e System time zone) which is set as UTC. So, Can I catch this exception and then update the value and proceed.

Comment: "Catch" what exception, and from where?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Function `NEW_TIME(...)` does not permit timezone value `UTC` - period. You have to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FROM_TZ` from convert a timestamp without a time zone to a timestamp with time zone (i.e. `UTC`) and then use `AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'` to convert it from the first time zone to the `GMT` time zone. You'll need to use `CAST` in various places as `FROM_TZ` expects a `TIMESTAMP` rather than a `DATE` and then you need to cast back to a `DATE` at the end (assuming you don't want a `TIMESTAMP` value):

```
SELECT CAST(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST( SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP ),
           'UTC'
         )
         AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
         AS DATE
       ) As gmt_time
FROM DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
| GMT_TIME            |
| :------------------ |
| 2019-04-10T14:05:37 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c74313d0418ddfea89ffe455cebc0121)*